# Can't parse outlook body using Tika on CentOS

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am attempting to parse the html body of an outlook message using Tika. When I run the following method on my windows machine it works fine, and I get the plain text representation of the email body.

```
private String parseHtml(InputStream stream) throws Exception {
    ContentHandler contenthandler = null;
    try {
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
        parser.parse(stream, contenthandler, metadata, new ParseContext());
        System.out.println(contenthandler.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contenthandler != null ? contenthandler.toString() : null;
}
```

However, when I run this same code on a CentOS VM, and physical server, I get all of the outlook markup. There is something happening in windows that allows Tika to detect the type of document that's not available on centos. The metadata shows that when I debug:

Windows: Content-Encoding=US-ASCII Generator=Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium) Content-Type=text/html; charset=us-ascii 
Linux:   Content-Encoding=US-ASCII Content-Type=text/plain; charset=US-ASCII

Comment: My first hunch is that you're missing some of the key Tika dependency jars on the CentOS machine. Are you *sure* you have the same set of jars on both?

Comment: You were right, add an answer and I'll choose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

You're missing some of the Tika jars or their dependencies

If you use the command line Tika App jar, then everything you need is in it, and it runs standalone. Likewise, the Tika Server jar is fully self contained.

For OSGi types, you need both the Tika Core and Tika Bundle, but that should be it as the bundle contains the Tika Parsers and their dependencies / references.

Otherwise, if you're using Tika from Java, you need Tika Core, Tika Parsers, and all of their respective dependencies. Maven can pull in the dependencies for you if you depend on `tika-core` and `tika-parsers`, but you still need to make sure that your deployment method carries those over.

If you miss out the Tika Parsers jar and/or its dependencies, then you'll still have Tika, but no parsers, so parsing won't return content. You can get the available parsers via the Tika Config object, and check from that that you have all the ones you expected.